# Accessing a method in a Singleton instance from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton, ninject

I use Ninject as my IOC.  I have two classes as shown below.

Customer:

```
public class Customer:ICustomer
{
   private ICustomerRepository _CustRepo;
   public Customer(ICustomerRepository custRepo){
     _CustRepo = custRepo;
   }

   public void CustomerOperations(int custId){

     var cust = _CustRepo.GetCustomer(custId);

     //Do something with the cust object     

     if(condition1)
      _CustRepo.Update(cust);
     if(condition2)
      _CustRepo.Delete(cust.id);
     if(condition3)
      _CustRepo.Insert(cust);
   }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class CustomerRepository:ICustomerRepository {

   private IDataAccessLayer _Dal;

   //Ctor details skipped

   public Customer GetCustomer(int custId) {//Get customer from DB}
   public bool Update(Customer c) {//Update}
   public bool Delete(int custID) {//Delete}
   public bool Insert(Customer c) {//Insert}
}
```

Bindings:

```
     Bind<ICustomer>().To<Customer>().InThreadScope();
     Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>().InSingletonScope();
```

Let's assume the scope can't be changed.  I am trying to sync the calls so thread1 doesn't delete the customer while thread2 is getting ready to update the same customer.

If locking is the recommended approach, how do I make sure the repository methods are thread safe. Thanks

Comment: I cannot offer a solution, but I can offer a hint. Don't sell your mule just to buy a plow. Static singletons (and/or static methods in general) are never the correct approach. Global state is just wrong. Do it the right way, using dependency injection. From a testable point of view, nobody will ever thank you by seeing a call to a static method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concurrency problem that locking can't solve.

Consider the following:
Client A requests the deletion of the customer before client B can make the call to delete it.  In this scenario the following occurs:

1. Client A acquires the lock on the customer/repository
2. Client B requests the lock, but has to wait until the lock is released by Client A
3. Client A successfully delete the customer
4. Client A releases the lock
5. Client B acquires the lock
6. Client B's request to update the customer fails because the customer has been deleted.

Look into the [concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) mechanisms of your underlying data store.

If you are using SQL Server + EF, take a look at this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As MattTannahill says, this is a concurrency problem.

The only way to accomplish what you want to accomplish is to defer the execution of the actual point of no return (update/delete), and do the proper book keeping prior to that to provide enough information to perform the right sequence or sequences of operation(s)... You will, for lack of a better explanation, remove concurrency from the equation of record manipulation.

So basically, you'd have a "transaction log/trail" of sorts associated with the record, and the actual operations on the record do not occur until a later moment when it's safe to do so. In the meantime, a record is stored in a state of "to be updated".

Of course, this opens up other things you need to resolve, and it can get unmanageable very quickly:

- How do you display an updated/deleted record that hasn't had the operation(s) performed on it yet.
- What transaction has final say?  What you're implying here is that updates should cancel out a concurrent delete.  Which you could do if you wait to perform all of the operations and analyze the transaction trail.  The rules to this kind of thing can get very complex over time because you essentially have to "mark a record for an operation" from a client interaction point of view, and then a process job to later to actually analyze and perform the operation.
- If a delete is "cancelled" by an update, since the operation occurs later, there's no immediate way of letting the user know it didn't delete. You'd have to figure out a way to let that user know.
- You'll need to define the "safe" time to perform these modifications.  Do you do it 30 seconds after no activity on the record?  Are there certain modifications that always take precedence?